# facebox open with ajax in user edit profile form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebox

I'm making a user profile edit form for my website, and I want to open facebox when a user clicks on the change password textbox. What changes can I do in my jQuery function?
Normally I'm using this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
 }) 
</script>
```

And my text field is:

```
<td>Change Password</td>
<td><input type="password" id="password1" name="password"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I decide to use this

```
    <label><a href="password.php" rel="facebox">Change Password</a></label>
```

and write jquery function

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
loadingImage : '<?php echo HTTP_PATH?>images/loading.gif',
closeImage   : '<?php echo HTTP_PATH?>images/closelabel.png'
})
    })
     </script>
```

and call this function

```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
```

and this solve my problem.thanks